# For loop is not executed

Tags: java, loops

Why isn't this loop executed?
At runtime woord.length() is equal to 5.

```
for (int j = woord.length(); j <= 0; j--)
{
//do some magic things here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `j` is equal to 5, then it is not smaller or equal to 0.

Comment: So the loops continues until the condition is met?

Comment: @Hypenate No, the loop continues only while the conditional expression evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Aha, that's different then VB.NET...
Thank you!

Comment: @Hypenate You're welcome. Might as well take a look at the [official Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). `When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.`

Answer (score 1):

```
j <= 0;
```

should be

```
j >= 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`j <= 0` will never be true if `j` has the value of 5 so it will never enter the `for` loop.

Changing to `j >= 0` would allow it to enter the loop,  however.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the operator... Probably you wanted to check

> >=

Your condition is never verified, as 5 is never <= 0, so the loop is never executed.